# preposition problem!

Tags: prepositions

i) Everyday drivers die ___ road accidents.

ii) The majority of road accidents are caused ___ human error.

iii) There occurs a lot of road accidents ___ Indian roads.

Please help me out by suggesting which prepositions will fit in the blank spaces. Also suggest multiple possibilities if available..

Comment: This appears to be a request for help with homework or a practice test, without any evidence of interest in the reason for the correct answer(s).

Comment: obviously I wanna learn so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than a preposition problem. Everyday, unless it is being used as an adjective, should be two words. Anyway, 1 is in, 2 is by, and 3 is on. Also, if you substitute the more proper word more for a lot, you will see that the verb should be occur.

Comment: So it seems the person who devised this test has an English problem.  Seriously, Rafat, you should try to find a better teacher. Two errors in the wording of three questions is terrible!

Comment: two errors? would you point out those please?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Three errors. *Everyday* should be "Every day," unless they really did mean "ordinary". Unfortunately the question is a candidate for deletion.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: I was counting that one.  I meant the same two that Moosie pointed out in the accepted answer. I counted the problem in iii) as only one error (agreement in number) although the syntax was awkward there as well. I didn't see anything wrong with ii)—did you?

Answer (score 0):

Everyday drivers die **in** road accidents

The majority of road accidents are caused **by** human error

There occurs a lot of road accidents **on** Indian roads

For the third sentence, it is possible to use "**along**".